# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I get error message

```
File "C:\Git\EDCEL-Process-Automation\newedceltrans.py", line 385, in add_data
    pdtpur     = ("ent_pdtpur + str(i)".get())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

See the function below:

```
def add_data():
    global count
    global rowno
    print(count)
    global valcount
    global cb_cust_pdtpur1
    global cb_cust_scmeasmt1
    global ent_cust_cstofpdt1
    global ent_cust_qntypur1
    global cb_cust_disrate1
    global ent_cust_disamt1
    global ent_cust_amtsld1
    global i
    global ent_pdtpur
    global ent_qntypur 
    global ent_rate     
    global ent_disamt 
    global ent_amtsld 
    global ent_tlamt   
    global Radvar1      
    i    =  i + 1
    print(i)
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
    #ent_cstsernum.set(count)
    ent_cstsernum = count
    rowno = rowno + 1
    valcount = valcount + 1
    #d = {}
    #for a in range(3):
    #d["group" + str(i)] = self.getGroup(selected, header+i)

    #ent_pdtpur1    = []
    #ent_pdtpur1.set('Select product')
    #ent_cstofpdt1   = tk.IntVar()
    #ent_qntypur1    = tk.IntVar()
    #ent_rate1       = tk.StringVar() 
    #ent_rate1.set('Select rate')
    #ent_disamt1     = tk.IntVar()
    #ent_amtsld1     = tk.IntVar()
    #ent_tlamt1      = tk.IntVar()
    #Radvar2         = tk.StringVar() 
    ent_cust_serialnum= ttk.Entry(prod_frame, width = 2, textvariable=ent_cstsernum)
    ent_cust_serialnum.grid(row=rowno, column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
    ent_cust_serialnum.insert(0, str(ent_cstsernum))
    ent_cust_serialnum.config(state='disabled')
    lbl_cust_pdtpur1= ttk.Label(prod_frame, text = "Product:")
    lbl_cust_pdtpur1.grid(row=rowno, column=1, sticky="W", padx=5, pady=5)
    cb_cust_pdtpur1=ttk.Combobox(prod_frame, width = 25, textvariable=("ent_pdtpur" + str(i)))
    cb_cust_pdtpur1['values'] = pro_records()
    cb_cust_pdtpur1.grid(row=rowno, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    #cb_cust_pdtpur.current() 
    #cb_cust_pdtpur.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="W", padx=5, pady=5)
    cb_cust_pdtpur1.current() 
    
    
    lbl_cust_scmeasmt1= ttk.Label(prod_frame, text = "Scale:")
    lbl_cust_scmeasmt1.grid(row=rowno, column=3, sticky="w", padx=5, pady=5)
    cb_cust_scmeasmt1=ttk.Combobox(prod_frame, width = 4, textvariable=("Radvar1" + str(i)))
    cb_cust_scmeasmt1['values'] = ('CTN',  
                                 'KG')                             
    cb_cust_scmeasmt1.grid(row=rowno, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)
  
    lbl_cust_cstofpdt1= ttk.Label(prod_frame, text = "Unit Price:")
    lbl_cust_cstofpdt1.grid(row=rowno, column=5,sticky="W", padx=5, pady=5)
    ent_cust_cstofpdt1= ttk.Entry(prod_frame, width = 10, textvariable=("ent_cstofpdt" + str(i)))
    ent_cust_cstofpdt1.grid(row=rowno, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)
    ent_cust_cstofpdt1.config(state='disabled')
      #ent_cust_cstofpdt= ttk.Entry(master=frm_form, width = 60, textvariable=ent_cstofpdt)
      #ent_cust_cstofpdt.bind("<Return>", pro_price) 
      #pro_price()
      #ent_cust_cstofpdt.insert(0, str(data))
      #ent_cust_cstofpdt.grid(row=3, column=4,sticky="W", padx=5, pady=5)

    lbl_cust_qntypur1= ttk.Label(prod_frame, text = "Qty Purchased:")
    lbl_cust_qntypur1.grid(row=rowno, column=7, sticky="W", padx=5, pady=5)
    ent_cust_qntypur1= ttk.Entry(prod_frame, width = 10, textvariable=("ent_qntypur" + str(i)))
    ##,validate='all',validatecommand=(vcmd, '%P'))
    ent_cust_qntypur1.grid(row=rowno, column=8,  padx=5, pady=5)
    
    lbl_cust_disamt1= ttk.Label(prod_frame, text = "Discount Type:")
    lbl_cust_disamt1.grid(row=rowno, column=9, sticky="W", padx=5, pady=5)

    cb_cust_disrate1=ttk.Combobox(prod_frame, width = 14, textvariable=("ent_rate" + str(i))) 
    cb_cust_disrate1['values'] = ('Percent',  
                             'Amount',
                            'None'  ) 
    cb_cust_disrate1.grid(row=rowno, column=10,  padx=5, pady=5)
      #cb_cust_disrate.current() 
    ent_cust_disamt1= ttk.Entry(prod_frame, width = 10, textvariable=("ent_disamt" + str(i)))
    ent_cust_disamt1.grid(row=rowno, column=11,  padx=5, pady=5)
    lbl_cust_amtsld1= ttk.Label(prod_frame, text = "Amt Sold:")
    lbl_cust_amtsld1.grid(row=rowno, column=12, sticky="W", padx=5, pady=5)
    ent_cust_amtsld1= ttk.Entry(prod_frame, width = 15, textvariable=("ent_amtsld" + str(i)))
    ent_cust_amtsld1.grid(row=rowno, column=13,  padx=5, pady=5)
    ent_cust_amtsld.config(state='disabled')
    pdtpur     = ("ent_pdtpur + str(i)".get())
```

Comment: Please change your code to a MWE, there are so many lines in this example that are not related to the error. Also, please add what you are trying to do in the line that is throwing the error.

Comment: what you want to `.get()` exactly?

Comment: .get() is to get the value of the textvariable ("ent_pdtpur + str(i)") entered by the user in the form

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the last line of the function:

```py
pdtpur     = ("ent_pdtpur + str(i)".get())
```

There appears to be two problems occurring. First, it looks as though you are trying to convert the index or integer value `i` to a str and append it to the "ent_pdtpur". But you need to move `str(i)` outside of the quotes:

```py
pdtpur     = "ent_pdtpur" + str(i)
```

The second issue is that you are trying to call the `.get()` method from a string object, but strings do not have this method or attribute. You can check what they have by executing `dir(str)` (FYI: `dir` is a useful method for getting all attributes and methods of an object). If you remove the `.get()` then your error will go away like in my second code block above.

Comment: I want to get the value of the textvariable entered by user that is why get() method    pdtpur     = "ent_pdtpur" + str(i).get()